# How can i copy values in specific cell of datagrid using wpf

Tags: c#

I am writing a small programm which can make some tasks at my university easier. I have started learning wpf, but i understand some other programming languages. I have chosen wpf because there are strong binding mechanism i have read about MVVM, this will be helpful for my programm.

I have 2 files, 1 is xml and the other is .csv. In the first step i have written a code to read the content of the xml and the csv file. i have created some datagrid template columns and i have bind the columns to elements of my xml file. I have 3 columns. (all read from xml, ID is at the beginning wrong, for this reason i need the csv file)

1 Name of students
2 Course they are visiting
3 ID Nr of course

each course has the same ID number, this id Number is in my .csv file the rest in xml.

i have created 5 textboxes, and in total i have 5 courses this semester.

each student is visiting every course (5)

i have 5 rows for each student (Name column A, Name appears 5 times) course name (column B) and column C should be the ID of the courses. I have also read the .csv file into an other datagrid (textbox is also an option). Each ID appears 1 time in my .csv file, i have about 100 students, 100 times the name of the same course ... doing this with excel is easy with a for next ...

The problem i have now, i don't know how i can copy the values (right now they are in textboxes, 1 ID in each) to the cells in my Datagrid? I have a button, for example .. i want to copy the values with click on the button. Here is my code: xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_ReadXml.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SummerSemester" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" MinHeight="300"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" MinWidth="500"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="StudentName">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="keyCellTextbox" Text="{Binding Path=Element[Name].Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Course">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="keyCellTextbox" Text="{Binding Path=Element[Course].Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="CellTextbox" Text="{Binding Path=Element[ID].Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Its not the best way to do this, i will find an other solution ..